# Mathematica stalling when attempting to "convert unit"

Tags: front-end

Twice now I have attempted to use the "convert unit" command on the bar below an output and it has caused the program to freeze, and not respond unless using the fix for the frozen kernal when opening the program.

Comment: If you are referring to using the Suggestions Bar, then this particular feature has been linked with quite a few malfunctions and problem, to the point that it may be best to simply turn it off entirely. See e.g. The following post from the pitfalls FAQ: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284